# returning string_view from function

Tags: c++, c++17, string-view

I am writing a lot of parser code where string_view excels, and have become fond of the type. I recently read ArthurO'Dwyer's article [std::string_view is a borrow type](https://quuxplusone.github.io/blog/2018/03/27/string-view-is-a-borrow-type/), where he concludes that string_view (and other 'borrow types') are fine to use as long as they "... appear only as function parameters and for-loop control variables." (with a couple of exceptions).

However, I have lately started to use string_view as return value for functions that convert enum to string (which I use a lot), like this [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/TTWYd9x75):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <algorithm>

enum class Color
{
    red, green, blue, yellow,
    last // Must be kept last
};
constexpr std::string_view toString(Color color); 

// The rest would normally be in a .cpp file

using cts = std::pair<Color, std::string_view>;
constexpr std::array colorNames = {cts{Color::red, "red color"},
                            cts{Color::green, "green color"},
                            cts{Color::blue, "blue color"},
                            cts{Color::yellow, "yellow color"}};

static_assert(colorNames.size() == static_cast<size_t>(Color::last));

constexpr std::string_view toString(Color color)
{
    // Normally calling a library function (which also checks for no match), instead of this:
    return std::ranges::find(colorNames, color, &cts::first)->second;
}

int main()
{
    auto s1 = toString(Color::green);
    auto s2 = toString(Color::blue);

    std::cout << s1 << ' ' << s2 << std::endl;
}
```

The reasons I have for doing it this way are:

1. By having it stored in an array as string_view, I can make the entire table constexpr.
2. By returning the string_view directly, there is no need of converting the string representation, so the entire function can be constexpr, or at least avoid creating unnecessary strings even when called with a non-constexpr parameter.
3. A side effect of having the table constexpr is that I can use static_assert to check that all elements of the enum are in the table, which is really great for catching additions to the enum. I really don't like having to put the 'last' enum value in there, but I don't see a better solution.

***So my question is really***, is returning the string_view this way unsafe (or UB) in any way, or can I keep on doing this with good conscience?

Alternatively, is there a better (faster/safer) way of solving this general problem of enum-to-string?

***Addition***: After reading G. Sliepen's very good answer, I'd like to add upon my comment to his answer: I often have the opposite function as well, e.g.:

```
constexpr Color fromString(string_view str)
{
  // No-match handling omitted
  return std::ranges::find(colorNames, color, &cts::second)->first;
}
```

In those situations I really do need the translation as a separate table so that it can be used by both functions. But in many other cases, the function containing a switch statement is the simplest and best.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> is returning the string_view this way unsafe (or UB) in any way, or **can I keep on doing this with good conscience**?

Yes. The way you use it is perfectly ok. The `string_view` returned by your `toString` function forms a view on data that will remain intact until the program terminates.

> Alternatively, is there a better (faster/safer) way of solving this general problem of enum-to-string?

You could make a `constexpr` function with a `switch`-statement inside it, like so:

```
constexpr std::string_view toString(Color color)
{
    switch (color) {
    case Color::red:   return "red";
    case Color::green: return "green";
    ...
    }
}
```

There should be no difference in efficiency if the function is evaluated at compile-time. But the compiler can check if you added `case`-statements for all the possible `Color`s, and if not it will give a warning. There's also no need for a `Color::last` this way.

Keeping both the `enum` and the `std::array` or `switch`-statement in sync can be annoying, especially if you have lots of enumeration values. [X macros](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro) might help here.

Comment: Yes, this is a good option. I didn't mention it in my original post, but in my code, the enum-string_view arrays are often used the other way too, e.g. in a function like `Color fromString(string_view str)`, which matches the second element of the pair to return the first. 
To handle this, I need the array, and not only a switch statement in the function. But otherwise you are right that a simple switch function (still returning string_view) may sometimes be better.

Comment: You can still use a chain of `if`-`else` statements instead of a `switch` to handle `fromString()`. But if that can't be evaluated at compile time (because `str` comes from some external input), it's better to use something like a `std::unordered_map` than a `std::array` if you have a large number of colors.

Comment: But if using if-else (or similar) inside the `fromString` function, I would suddenly need to have the enum-string_view info duplicated, in both the `toString` and `fromString` function  - and that is something I would never do.

Comment: Sure, although that's where X macros could help as well. You can just have a single `std::array` that maps enum values to strings, but searching that at run time is potentially going to be slow. Another alternative is to use something like a [`Boost::Bimap`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html). Or perhaps this [Magic Enum](https://github.com/Neargye/magic_enum) library is something you could use. Maybe with C++23 we will get langauge support for [reflection](https://matus-chochlik.github.io/mirror/doc/html/reflexpr/example/enum_to_string.html).

Comment: I guess X macros could help, but we have a pretty strict "no macros" standard (which I support) in my company. I am aware of the possibilities that will open up with reflection, and really, really hope I can use that in a couple of years. Those two others look very interesting though, thanks :-)